# Thunderbird through proxy (Proxy is listening on port 8080)

Tags: networking, proxy, thunderbird

In my college, I have a proxy server which is listening on port 8080. I want to run Thunderbird. I am not sure about which protocol this proxy is for. I would be happy to help you out, if you can tell me how to check this. (I am sorry about this lack of knowledge)

**System Specs** Windows 7, 3 GB RAM, High Speed LAN connection.

And I have been trying to do that for quite some time now. Some of the things I tried

1. The following commands:

```
    netsh
    winhttp
    import proxy source=ie
```

These are the commands that are used to get the Windows App Store to work in Windows 8. I thought that if I do this, then all the traffic that any application requests is tunelled through the proxy by the system. (Please pardon my bad technical term usage! I don't know anything about networking and this is my layman understanding of this problem.)

2. I tried a program called pCap.

Both the above solutions did not work.

please provide a solution to either run Thunderbird (Gmail) or suggest another mail client which can run Gmail fluently under the conditions described above.

**I am not behind a corporate proxy.**

**Please help me out with the above situation.**

Comment: What exactly does "port 8080 is open" mean? Are you referring to the port the proxy is listening on?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the language. I will correct it.

Comment: I assume this is an HTTP proxy. Is a SOCKS proxy available?